# how to open a static html file from an ip using file://?

Tags: html, activex

i need to open a static html file from ip 192.168.##.##. my problem is, i cant access the file using file://192.168.##.##/folder/names/ACT2-1.html i need to open it using file:// not http:// to run the ActiveX in IE.

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq): Server Fault is for _Information Technology Professionals_ needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a **professional capacity**. You seem to be asking an end-user question regarding very basic Windows or Internet Explorer functionality. Perhaps you should consider clarifying your question.

Comment: ActiveX Seriously?  What is this 1996?

Answer (score 2):

The `file:` protocol can only be used to access files on your local machine.

Comment: so how can i access the html file and run the activeX?

Comment: Go to "My Computer", find the file, and double click on it?

Comment: i need to open it on IE browser and run the activex.